# special case ssh connection lag

Tags: ssh, debian

**Setup**

We have a DMZ and LAN in our office that are connected to the outside with the following setup:

```
+------+
|      |------> LAN (normal office router)
|Modem |
|      |------> DMZ (a single machine)
+------+
```

Our internet account is with Comcast and we have 5 status IPs, one of which points to the single machine in the DMZ.

**Problem**

ssh connections initiated ANYWHERE EXCEPT the office LAN are *really fast*. However, from the LAN, there is about a 5 second delay. WTF??

**Extra info**

The DMZ machine is debian 5.

Executing a `wget` to the DMZ has no lag.

When executing the following, everything up to `HERE IS WHERE THE LAG IS INCURRED` executes immediately.

```
ssh -vvvv sam@dmz.com

...
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1015
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1063
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/id_rsa (0x22440830)
debug2: key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1127`


HERE IS WHERE THE LAG IS INCURRED


debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1495
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/shopkins/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/shopkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/shopkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sam@dmz.com's password:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably having to wait for the reverse DNS lookup to timeout/fail.

Try setting this in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** (assuming you are using the default install of openssh) and see if that fixes your issue.

```
UseDNS no
```

Comment: Awesome! Just out of curiosity, what is going on behind the scenes here and why is the lag only incurred when connecting from within the office?

Comment: The machine is doing a reverse DNS lookup on your IP address and for one reason or another (most likely your IP address doesn't have a valid reverse DNS address or it is a private address) can't find a valid PTR record and so has to wait for the DNS lookup to timeout (normally 1-2 seconds per resolver). Connecting from other places is fine because they have proper reverse DNS (PTR) records.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `"UseDNS no"` into the file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** on the **destination** host which you are trying to connect to.

Be careful about the difference between **sshd_config** and **ssh_config**.

You have to restart the ssh daemon on the destination host :

(For FreeBSD)

```
/etc/rc.d/sshd restart
```